# Using a Force Sensing Resistor and time input

Tags: sensors, time

So the code below measures how much force is exerted on the FSR. I would like to know what would I have to change in this code so that it can record for how long the FSR is being pressed for. So instead of "What force is exerted on the FSR?", I want to ask "How long is the FSR being pressed for?"

Any help will be most appreciated

```
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Wire.h>
SoftwareSerial bluetooth_port(0, 1); //ports for Rx and Tx
int flexSensorPin; // The flex sensor for pin 0 

void setup() 
{

  Serial.begin(9600); // Start the serial transmission
}


void loop() 
{ 

  flexSensorPin = analogRead(A0); // Flex sensor pin 
  Serial.print(flexSensorPin);
  Serial.println("EOL");

  delay(100);

}
```

Comment: check out the `millis()` function

Comment: you need to clarify your question ... is `somewhere around 3 seconds` an acceptable measurement of time?

Comment: When there's no "force" read the sensor value and then start counting, something like: `if(sernsorReading != 0){start counting}`

Answer (score 1):

Use the analog comparator implemented in AVRs. this function, monitors two analog levels and generates interrupts if one of them goes higher or lower than the other as set. use this interrupt to record/stop counting. on AIN connects to FSR, and the other to a potentiometer to define a threshold. here are some links to get you going.

http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11916
https://github.com/tardate/LittleArduinoProjects/tree/master/playground/AnalogComparator

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely check these links out